# Parallel make with standalone package

Tags: standalone, build-system, makefile

This question is a LaTeX question, although it might actually be resolved by changing the build procedure of the document instead of the document itself.

I have a document that includes a bunch of subfiles, where each has preamble of its own. I use the `standalone` package to accomplish this.

Now I have two versions of my `main.tex` file, where each only contains the preamble and an `\include{...}` list of all the subfiles. The two `main` files compile fine, each yielding a layout-wise different version of the document (one optimized for A4 printing, using two-column layout and somesuch, and one that is for ebook displays).

Now I have a Makefile that builds both versions of the document. But since Make builds the two independent documents at the same time, pdfLaTeX is run on the standalone sub-documents separately and in parallel, causing all kinds of awkward errors, since files are written and read at the same time by two different instances of pdfLaTeX.

I can think of several solutions to this problem, but wanted to ask for suggestions:

- Simply don't build the two documents simultaneously. Easiest solution, but somewhat unsatisfactory.
- Don't use `standalone` and remove preamble from subfiles. Since I have ~30 subfiles, this would be non negelegible amount of open-and-delete-work, plus I like the feature of being able to compile the subdocuments separately for developement/debugging.
- Use an alternative to `standalone` that doesn't have this problem (is there one?)
- Somehow tell `standalone` to use different filenames for the helper files for the two different document versions (my favourite, but I don't know if it's possible)

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can force `make` to execute sequentially - google found this stackoverflow solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838851/multiple-targets-build-in-makefile

Comment: if you just have the `\include` version you can process individual files with `pdflatex \includeonly{file1}\input main`

Comment: If the dependencies are well set, `make` should compile things in the right order. Another question is how to generate the dependencies automatically from the source files (like `makedepend`)

Comment: It's not clear to me why you are running two pdfLaTeX runs at the same time: what's wrong with doing them sequentially? `make` should be doing that anyway!